# Mock multiple capsuled GraphQL requests in JEST

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, redux-saga

I will test my redux-sagas, and stuck by mocking my api requests.
The scenario is like this:

I have a GraphQL API and each request is capsuled (axios) in a requestApiUtil.

like

/path/api/sampleOneApiRequest.js

```js
import { requestApi } from 'utils';

export const sampleOneApiRequest = ({ arg1 }) => requestApi.query(`
  sampleData {
    id
  }
`)
```

/path/api/sampleTwoApiRequest.js

```js
import { requestApi } from 'utils';

export const sampleTwoApiRequest = ({ arg1 }) => requestApi.query(`
  otherSampleData {
    id
  }
`)
```

/path/api/index.js

```js
export * from './sampleOneApiRequest';
export * from './sampleTwoApiRequest';
```

the saga that i like to test, looks like this

/path/redux/saga/sampleSaga/sampleSaga.js

```js
import { all, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { successAction, failureAction } from 'path/redux/action';
import { sampleOneApiRequest, sampleTwoApiRequest } from 'path/api';

export function* sampleSaga({ payload }) {
  const switch = payload ? payload.switch : false;
  try {
    let response;
    if (switch) {
      response = (yield sampleOneApiRequest());
    } else {
      response = (yield sampleTwoApiRequest());
    }

    if (response.errors) {
      return yield put(failureAction(response.errors));
    }

    yield put(successAction(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(failureAction(error));
  }
}
```

Now to the problem, my test to the saga looks like this:

/path/redux/saga/sampleSaga/sampleSaga.test.js

```js
import { sampleSaga } from './sampleSaga';
import { sampleOneApiRequest, sampleTwoApiRequest } from 'path/api';
import { successAction } from 'path/redux/action';
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

jest.mock('path/api', () => ({
  sampleOneApiRequest: async () => { id: 'sample1' },
  sampleTwoApiRequest: async () => { id: 'sample2' }
}));

descripe('test sampleSaga', () => {
  
  if('test sampleSaga switch false', () => {
    const generator   = sampleSaga({ payload: { switch: false } });
    const apiResponse = { data: { id: 'sample1' } };
    
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(sampleOneApiRequest());
    expect(generator.next(apiResponse).value).toEqual(put(successAction(apiResponse)))
  });
  
  if('test sampleSaga switch true', () => {
    const generator   = sampleSaga({ payload: { switch: true } });
    const apiResponse = { data: { id: 'sample2' } };
    
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(sampleTwoApiRequest());
    expect(generator.next(apiResponse).value).toEqual(put(successAction(apiResponse)))
  });

});
```

The problem is, that the second triggert saga, generate a request to the backend, but i aspect the the request to the backend will be mocked. The frist one will mocked perfectly, when i change the order of both tests, always still the second one (in order) will be call to the backend. When i comment out the first test, the second works fine.

I don't know what its wrong.

Comment: Can you show the error details？

Comment: The error is, that the second request make a request to the backend (the server respond with a 401 error, because no auth token). But i prefer to mock both requests.